# Is there a k8s equivalent to `ContainerExecCreate` in docker Golang sdk?

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes

I can use `ContainerExecCreate` in docker Golang SDK to return a hijacked response from the docker container.

I want to do the same thing for container on k8s cluster. Is there a equivalent to `ContainerExecCreate` in k8s sdk?

I know there is https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.6.1/test/e2e/framework/exec_util.go which returns stdout of shell command, but what I want is the hijacked response.